# My request times out when using Content-Type="application/json"

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a specific API call that simply times out when using Content-Type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8".

If I remove this header (I'm just trying this via the Google Postman client), I immediately receive a response.

I'm using Laravel PHP to return a response.

I feel like I may be missing something extremely obvious, such as some config setting not allowing this content-type, but I'm not sure which direction to be looking.

Code:

Route file:
`Route::post('getUserStats', 'UsersController@getUserStats');`

Response function:

```
public function getUserStats(Request $request) {

    return Response::JSON(array('foo'=>'bar'));

    $input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $input = json_decode($input);
    $userEmail = $input->customer->email;
    $user = User::where('email', $userEmail)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        return 'no user match for email: ' . $userEmail;
    }

    return $user->buildStatsHTML();

}
```

Notice I am simply trying to return anything to start, I've also simply tried to return a string to no avail.

The request being sent is simply `localhost:8000/api/tokenAuth/getUserStats` with the header `"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"`.

Comment: post your code example first

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: Dear T-rex, what is this `$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');`? Why on Earth would you not use `$request->input()`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Regardless of the syntax I don't get to that line.